# Django - filter( __icontains) doesn't work

Tags: django

Please, help with trouble:

```
class SearchResultView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "search_result.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        location = self.request.GET['location']
        locations_searched = Location.objects.filter(name__icontains=location)
        context['locations_searched'] = locations_searched
        return context

class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    location = forms.CharField(label=u"Локация:")
```

When entering capitalized word in location field I can see result in the view, but when not capitalized - nothing is shown in the view

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an SQlite database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am guessing you are using an SQLite database and have some non-ASCII characters in the input. From the SQLite [FAQs](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18):

> Case-insensitive matching of Unicode characters does not work.
>   The default configuration of SQLite only supports case-insensitive comparisons of ASCII characters. The reason for this is that doing full Unicode case-insensitive comparisons and case conversions requires tables and logic that would nearly double the size of the SQLite library.

Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#substring-matching-and-case-sensitivity) also mentions this:

> For all SQLite versions, there is some slightly counter-intuitive
>   behavior when attempting to match some types of strings. These are
>   triggered when using the iexact or contains filters in Querysets...

Comment: thanks a lot! does it turn out I have to realize this by myself? may be through uppercase/lowercase transforming? or may be I just should change DB :)

Comment: Will you be using SQlite in production (not recommended!)? If not then the issue should go away once you switch to a production database like Postgres or MySQL. Otherwise, yes, you will probably have to manually lowercase the input before passing it to the filter.